CF7 "ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined"
When I run PageSpeed Insight on ChoicePlumbingOrlando.com, I get this error:
"ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at https://choiceplumbingorlando.com/wp-content/plugins/cf7-redirection/js/wpcf7-redirect-script.js:1:1"
I added the following to function.php ... but still getting these errors on every page.
// Disable Contact Form 7 Unless Called add_filter( 'wpcf7_load_js', '__return_false' ); add_filter( 'wpcf7_load_css', '__return_false' );


The error message appears to be caused by the plugin cf7-redirection, not cf7 itself.

@CBroe I do not have such plugin ... but I'll check if such is a function\feature of another plugin.
Thank You Kindly

@CBroe  THANK YOU !
I was able to deactivate the attached plugin (I did not add this plugin hence didn't know) and it solved the issue.
Plugin Name:
Successful Redirection for Contact Form 7
Activate | Delete
Successful Redirection for Contact Form 7 - Redirect after mail sent.
Version 1.0 | By JAYASREE TU | View details

SOLVED!
I was able to deactivate the plugin "Redirection for Contact Form 7"
(I did not add this plugin hence didn't know) and it solved the issue.
Plugin: Redirection for Contact Form 7 Activate.
Generated error on PageSpeed Insights: "CF7 "ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined""

Put the solution i the answer, not just comments.
